# writing to a specified line using c#

Tags: c#, streamwriter

what i have atm is a searchbox and 4 lists
the lists are
banlists
banned
limited
semi limited

now what i want to do is when i drag an item from my search box write it to a text file with a number next to it depending on what list it was added to(done)
now i need to know how to write to a certain line
example

the text document works like this

```
#Built using DevPro card editor. !new
#forbidden 
1 0
#limit 
1027 1
#semi limit 
12376 2
```

the way i have it working now prints it like this

```
#Built using DevPro card editor.
!new
#forbidden
#limit
#semi limit
1 0
1027 1
12376 2
```

i want it to write like the first example so if i drag an item to the banned list it writes it under #forbidden same with the other 2 this is the code im currently using for my drag drop event

```
private void List_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    int cardid = Int32.Parse((string)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text));
    var list = (ListBox)sender;
    int indexOfItemUnderMouseToDrop = list.IndexFromPoint(list.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y)));
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.StringFormat))
    {
        if (!BannedList.Items.Contains(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text)) && !LimitedList.Items.Contains(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text))
                && !SemiLimitedList.Items.Contains(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text)))
        {
            if (indexOfItemUnderMouseToDrop >= 0 && indexOfItemUnderMouseToDrop < list.Items.Count)
                {
                list.Items.Insert(indexOfItemUnderMouseToDrop, e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text));
                }
            else
            {
                list.Items.Add(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text));
                if (BannedList.Items.Contains(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text)))
                {
                    using (var writer = new StreamWriter("lflist.conf", true))
                    writer.WriteLine(Program.CardData[cardid].Id + " 0");
                }
                else if (LimitedList.Items.Contains(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text)))
                {
                    using (var writer = new StreamWriter("lflist.conf", true))
                    writer.WriteLine(Program.CardData[cardid].Id + " 1");
                }
                else if (SemiLimitedList.Items.Contains(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text)))
                {
                    using (var writer = new StreamWriter("lflist.conf", true))
                    writer.WriteLine(Program.CardData[cardid].Id + " 2");
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {                    
            if (BannedList.Items.Contains(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text)))
                MessageBox.Show(Program.CardData[cardid].Name + " is already contained in the Banned list.");
            else if (LimitedList.Items.Contains(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text)))
                MessageBox.Show(Program.CardData[cardid].Name + " is already contained in the Limited list.");
            else if (SemiLimitedList.Items.Contains(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text)))
                MessageBox.Show(Program.CardData[cardid].Name + " is already contained in the SemiLimited list.");
        }
    }
}
```

so in other words the question is how do i make stream writer find a line and write on the line under it

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to simply build the whole thing into a string and then `File.WriteAllText` it?

Comment: probaly but then i would have to rewrite all the code which i dont really want to do as it took me weeks to get it working this way

Comment: if its not possible it dont really matter it just made the file neater looking

Comment: This just isn't possible, text files don't have a fixed record length.  The *stream* in StreamWriter was not an accident.

Comment: ok thought it was worth a try thanks anyway

Comment: As an alternative to *kind of* make it work like you want; Maintain a List<string>, that way you can find the index of say "#limit" and insert at index - 1, then at the end or when you press a button, you can write each item in the List to a separate line in the text file. It does mean re-creating the entire file each time you make a change, but it's probably the best option if you want to be inserting at particular lines.

Comment: problem with that is the search box searchs a list of names each name is referenced to a number so therefore when rewriting the file i would have to get the number of each item and write it in the text file which i dk how to do as of yet